# How to fix the forbidden and unexpected token in json at position 0 in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

```
const [forecastData, setForecastData] = useState({ forecast: []});
    useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;

        const FETCHDATA = async () => {
                await fetch(forecast,{
                    headers : { 
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      'Accept': 'application/json'
                     }
              
                  }).then((res) => res.json()).then((response) => {
                response.daily.data.shift();
                response.daily.data.pop();

                const DATA = response.data.map(
                    (dailyData) =>
                        new DailyForecast(
                            dailyData.summary,
                            dailyData.temperatureMax.toFixed(0) + '°C',
                            dailyData.time,
                            dailyData.icon
                        )
                )
    
                    if (!ignore) setForecastData({ forecast: DATA })
                })
        }
        FETCHDATA();
        return () => { ignore = true;}
    }, []);
```

I have a problem when I run the code the error is ```GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/db9249f6adf5c8d4e27736cc9fa50e11/12.8797,121.7740?units=si 403 (Forbidden) Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0````

Comment: Your request is being *denied* the json response you desire

Comment: Looks like the request is made against the wrong endpoint? Shouldn't it be `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/db9249f6adf5c8d4e27736cc9fa50e11/12.8797,121.7740?units=si`? Check your `forecast` variable.

Comment: @juliomalves but I'm getting an error which is ```Access to fetch at 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/db9249f6adf5c8d4e27736cc9fa50e11/12.8797,121.7740?units=si' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301

This is the reason, the proxy (cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com) stopped working a week ago. I am trying to find the solution myself now.

**Update:** found alternative proxy! Here is the fix:
replace `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`
with `https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=`

Problem solved!